# How to store the result of a SQL Job that runs a stored procedure into a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

Basically this is the scenario I am trying to accomplish here.

I have a stored procedure that runs against a table. The stored procedure is a simple SQL query. Once the query is done, it inserts the results into another table.

I've created a SQL Server Job that executes that stored procedure on a daily basis (once a day) and it works perfectly.

What I want to do now is to insert some other data on another table once the SQL Server Job is completed. This second table needs to contain two columns, `Day` and `AddedRows`.

This last table will help me out to know on each day how many rows were inserted into the first table once the stored procedure was executed by the job.

Is this scenario doable? Could you give me some pointers?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you alter the existing stored procedure? If not is there any indicator in the first table that lets you recognise which are new rows and which aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another insert statement inside your first stored procedure which insert rows into the First table.

Something like.....

```
Declare @Count INT;  

-- Actual Insert statement in the procedure 
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1) , (2) , (3)

-- Capture the number of rows inserted
SELECT @Count = @@ROWCOUNT;

-- Insert into table2 
INSERT INTO Table2([Day] ,AddedRows)
VALUES (GETDATE() , @Count)
```

Comment: Awesome! I never thought it could be that easy! Thanks a lot for your help!